I tried to enable the remove option on cart to remove cart item by adding the some code, result come in following error
I have added the code to enable the remove option on the cart. the following error occurs.
Reverse for 'remove_cart_item' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/remove_cart_item/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<cart_item_id>[0-9]+)/$']
cart.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<!-- ============================ COMPONENT 1 ================================= -->
{% if not cart_items%}
<h2 class="text-center">Your shopping cart is empty</h2>
<br>
<div class="text-center">
<a href="{% url 'store' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue Shopping</a>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-lg-9">
<div class="card">
<table class="table table-borderless table-shopping-cart">
<thead class="text-muted">
<tr class="small text-uppercase">
  <th scope="col">Product</th>
  <th scope="col" width="120">Quantity</th>
  <th scope="col" width="120">Price</th>
  <th scope="col" class="text-right" width="200"> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
    {% for cart_item in cart_items %}
    <td>
        <figure class="itemside align-items-center">
            <div class="aside"><img src="{{ cart_item.product.images.url }}" class="img-sm"></div>
            <figcaption class="info">
                <a href="{{ cart_item.product.get_url }}" class="title text-dark">{{cart_item.product.product_name}}</a>
                <p class="text-muted small">
                    {% if cart_item.variations.all %}
                        {% for item in cart_item.variations.all %}
                            {{item.variation_category |capfirst }} : {{item.variation_value | capfirst}} <br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %} 
                </p>    
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <!-- col.// -->
                    <div class="col"> 
                        <div class="input-group input-spinner">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <a href="{% url 'remove_cart' cart_item.product.id cart_item.id %}" class="btn btn-light" type="button" id="button-plus"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </a>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{cart_item.quantity}}">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                            <form action="{% url 'add_cart' cart_item.product.id %}" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% for item in cart_item.variations.all %}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="{{item.variation_category | lower}}" value="{{item.variation_value | capfirst}}">
                                {% endfor %}
                                <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit" id="button-minus"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </button>
                            </form>
                            </div>      
                        </div> <!-- input-group.// -->
                    </div> <!-- col.// -->
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="price-wrap"> 
            <var class="price">${{cart_item.sub_total}}</var> 
            <small class="text-muted"> ${{cart_item.product.price}} each</small> 
        </div> <!-- price-wrap .// -->
    </td>
    <td class="text-right"> 
    <a href="{% url 'remove_cart_item' cart_item.product.id cart_item.id %}" class="btn btn-danger"> Remove</a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div> <!-- card.// -->

    </aside> <!-- col.// -->
    <aside class="col-lg-3">

        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <dl class="dlist-align">
              <dt>Total price:</dt>
              <dd class="text-right">{{total}}</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="dlist-align">
              <dt>Tax:</dt>
              <dd class="text-right"> {{tax}}</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="dlist-align">
              <dt>Grand Total:</dt>
              <dd class="text-right text-dark b"><strong>${{grand_total}}</strong></dd>
            </dl>
            <hr>
            <p class="text-center mb-3">
                <img src="{% static './images/misc/payments.png' %}" height="26">
            </p>
            <a href="./place-order.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Checkout </a>
            <a href="{% url 'store' %}" class="btn btn-light btn-block">Continue Shopping</a>
        </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
        </div> <!-- card.// -->

</aside> <!-- col.// -->


</div> <!-- row.// -->
{% endif %}
<!-- ============================ COMPONENT 1 END .// ================================= -->

</div> <!-- container .//  -->
</section>
<!-- ========================= SECTION CONTENT END// ========================= -->

{% endblock %}

urls.py file of the carts app
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('add_cart/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('remove_cart/<int:product_id>/<int:cart_item_id>/', views.remove_cart, name='remove_cart'),
    path('remove_cart_item/<int:product_id>/<int:cart_item_id>/', views.remove_cart_item, name='remove_cart_item'),

]

views.py file of the carts app

# Create your views here.
def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart

def add_cart(request, product_id): 
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)  #get the product
    product_variation = []
    if request.method=='POST':
        for item in request.POST:
            key=item
            value=request.POST[key]
            
            try:
                variation=Variation.objects.get(product=product, variation_category__iexact=key, variation_value__iexact=value)
                product_variation.append(variation)
            except:
                pass

    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))  #get the cart using the cart_id present in the session
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)
        )
    cart.save()

    is_cart_item_exists = CartItem.objects.filter(product=product, cart=cart).exists()
    if is_cart_item_exists:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.filter(product=product, cart=cart)
        # existing_variations ->database
        # current_variations -> product_variation
        # item_id -> database
        ex_var_list = []
        id = []
        for item in cart_item:
            existing_variation = item.variations.all()
            ex_var_list.append(list(existing_variation))
            id.append(item.id)

        print(ex_var_list)

        if product_variation in ex_var_list:
            # increase the cart item quantity
            index = ex_var_list.index(product_variation)
            item_id = id[index]
            item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, id=item_id)
            item.quantity += 1
            item.save()
        else:
            # create a new cart item
            item = CartItem.objects.create(product=product, quantity=1, cart=cart)
            if len(product_variation) > 0:
                item.variations.clear()
                item.variations.add(*product_variation)     
            item.save()
    else:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product = product,
            quantity = 1,
            cart = cart,
        )
        if len(product_variation) > 0:
            cart_item.variations.clear()
            cart_item.variations.add(*product_variation)
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('cart')

def remove_cart(request, product_id, cart_item_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product = product, cart = cart, id=cart_item_id)
        if cart_item.quantity > 1:
            cart_item.quantity -= 1
            cart_item.save()
        else:
            cart_item.delete()
    except:
        pass
    return redirect('cart')

def remove_cart_item(request, product_id, cart_item_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product = product, cart = cart, id=cart_item_id)
    cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart')
    
def cart(request, total=0, quantity=0, cart_items= None):
    try:
        tax = 0
        grand_total = 0
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, is_active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
            quantity += cart_item.quantity
        tax = (total * 2) / 100
        grand_total = total + tax
        
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass # just ignore
    context = {
        'total': total,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'cart_items': cart_items,
        'tax': tax,
        'grand_total': grand_total,
        }

    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def __str__(self):
    return self.cart_item

trace stack
Internal Server Error: /cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\carts\views.py", line 124, in cart       
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'remove_cart_item' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/remove_cart_item/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<cart_item_id>[0-9]+)/$']


Django typically also shows the error with the fragment of the template that generates the code, so can you look what part of the template produces the error?

I think this part is generating an error but I failed to trace that                    
 Remove


was there at any point previously, a {% url 'remove_cart_item ... %} with only one parameter.

Please stop reposting this question to bypass the closure. As I mentioned in the previous one edit the original to resolve the closure reason. As a hint to you you're still lacking a [mre], you might want to have a look at base.html (The template you show extends it) and see if it has a url tag for remove_cart_item in it.

In your urls.py, the remove_cart_item path is defined as requiring two arguments: product_id and cart_item_id
path('remove_cart_item/<int:product_id>/<int:cart_item_id>/', views.remove_cart_item, name='remove_cart_item')

Errors:
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'remove_cart_item' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/remove_cart_item/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<cart_item_id>[0-9]+)/$']

The error said the functions need two params but got 0 so you should pass params like this to slove the errors:
<a href="{% url 'remove_cart_item' product_id=cart_item.product.id cart_item_id=cart_item.id %}" class="btn btn-danger"> Remove</a>

This syntax explicitly matches the parameters defined in the urls.py file, ensuring they are passed correctly.
If you error won't slove then see the value of productid and cart id by printing
print(cart_item.id)


nice explain by Charita Shrestha
